# Sequelize.js create too many callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, sequelize.js

developping a restful app with nodejs, expressjs and sequelizejs, I found my code doing a lot of callbacks.

In particular when I'm dealing with association and creating object in db like so:

```
// db is my database object

// here are my db entities : header, line and thing
// header has many   line 
// line   belongs to header
// line   has one    thing
// thing  has many   line

db.line.create().success(function(line){
  db.header.find({where:{id : header_id}}).success(function(header){
    header.addLine(line).success(function(){
      db.thing.find({where:{id : thing_id}}).success(function(thing){
        line.setThing(thing).success(function(){
          // OK
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I wanted to use `return` statement inside error callback but I wouldn't be able to get the created data.

Do you think there is another way to do such operations without all the callbacks?

Comment: StrongLoop has a good article relating to this http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/

Comment: Sequelize 2.0 natively supports promises via [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

Answer (score 1):

With previous example this is what promises would look likes in my example of creating and associating :

```
// db is my database object

// here are my db entities : header, line and thing
// header has many   line 
// line   belongs to header
// line   has one    thing
// thing  has many   line

db.line.create().success(function(line){
  db.header.find({where:{id : header_id}
  }).then(function(header){
    header.addLine(line);
  }).then(function(){
    return db.thing.find({where:{id : thing_id}
  }).then(function(thing){
    line.setThing(thing);
  }).then(function(){
    // OK 
  }).catch(function(err){
    // handle errors of association
  });
.error(function(err){
   // handle errors of creation
});
```